# Model.find Mongoose 6.012 always return all documents even though having filter

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

A sample of my schema,

```
const XXXSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
}
```

I am using mongoose for awhile, and just recently I started experience the issues. The following query works as expected,

```
await MyModel.find({_id: ObjectId(SOME NUMBER)}).exec()
```

However, it always returns all documents if I query using any other fields, regardless value. For example,

```
await MyModel.find({anotherField: "some value"}).exec()
```

I tried to use callback, but the result is the same. Could someone help?
The mongodb version I use is 5.0.2.
Thanks.

---

Update: I reviewed mongoose query debug, and found, mongoose ignored my filter, and only send an empty {} as the filter.

Comment: please debug you query what is being happening in background or share the debug logs

Comment: You can use the fields defined in your schema to filter the data. Please include your document schema with the fields you are trying to filter with.

Comment: It doesn't matter which field, because that happens to all fields in my schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the due to a syntax error, my schema was not be used to create the corresponding model, and thus mongoose did not recognize the field I used to query.

Comment: This was my problem too.

Comment: In my case I had several child models of a parent model... querying parent with a property that doesn't exist on `ALL` children models will also lead to see this bug. without any notices. 
you can also try enabling mongoose debug mode before your query.

Answer (score 3):

its because you don't have any field in schema named as "anotherField", Always make sure to check your find method filter field or key Name.

i.e `.find({ correctFieldName: fieldValue })`.

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `strict` or `strictQuery` to false when declaring `Schema`.

```
new Schema({ field: Number }, { strictQuery: false })
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strictQuery

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same issue after i start using Mongoose 6 version and the exact same code works in 5+ version. Below is my code where i am using a existing collection in my mongodb which will retrieve urls of Production environment based on the condition. No matter what i change it is returning all the documents and not based on the filter query. Finally i found out that from 6+ version, we need to specify the schema even though we are pointing to the existing collection in DB.

Below you can see i am using existing collection name in the model function call

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const URLDetailsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
      space: String // Added this change
});

const URLDetailsModel = mongoose.model(
  "URLDetailsModel",
  URLDetailsSchema,
  "uip_pcf_urls"
);

module.exports = URLDetailsModel;
```

This is my find call

```js
const records = await URLDetailsModel.find({ space: "PROD" });
```