# Log a user in and get their profile

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express

I am attempting to log a user in to my DB. When I log the user in, it returns the first userId in the DB and not the user who logged in. I have been struggling with this for a while and really am at a dead end.

This is my POST route to log the user in:

```
// login
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
  });
  const secret = process.env.SECRET;
  if (!user) {
    return res.status(400).send("the user not found!");
  }
  if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.passwordHash)) {
    const token = jwt.sign(
      {
        userId: user.id,
        isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      },
      secret,
      { expiresIn: "1d" }
    );
    res.status(200).send({ user: user.email, token: token });
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("password is wrong!");
  }
});
```

The   `const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email, });` this returns the wrong user.
When I query the endpoint get a users profile with the `userId` it gets the right information. So its got nothing to do with the DB.

This is the call in the app.

```
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    axios
      .post(`${baseURL}users/login`, {
        email: email,
        passwordHash: password,
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log('USER ID TOKEN', res.data.token);
        setbearerToken(res.data.token);
        AsyncStorage.setItem('bearerToken', res.data.token);
        const decoded = decode(res.data.token);
        setTokenID(decoded.userId);
        dispatch(setUser(res.data));
      });
  };
```

user.js model

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    contactName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 50
    },
    passwordHash: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        minlength: 5,
        maxlength: 1024
    },
    token: {
        type: String,
    },
    isAdmin: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    clubName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    clubAddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    clubEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    clubPhone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    clubWebsite: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    clubContact: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})
```

Comment: Are there multiple users with the same email in the database?

Comment: @user18309290 No

Comment: Just to ensure. The call in the app ...`users/login` hits the `router.post("/login", ...)` route?

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall I dropped the table and recreated a new user. No problem and logged the user in

Comment: Ok. What was the difference between your original and the new table? Have you also changed the code? It looked good to me. Good that it is working now.

Comment: @ChristianUnnerstall No I never changed anything but its still logging in the first user only. I also added the `index` tag to the `user.js` model

Comment: Can you post the user.js model and your imports for the router file? If `User.findOne` is pointing to the right collection it should bring back the user with `email` equal `req.body.email` or nothing.

Comment: Do you also have a model? Only see schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema doesn't have a field `email` to filter on.

```
const user = await User.findOne({
    email: req.body.email,
});
```

Maybe you try `clubEmail` field. I reproduced the behavior and it looks like that mongoose ignores the filter if the field does not exist in the Schema an just returns the first document in the collection.

E.g.

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        age: Number
    }
)

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOne({name: "Superman"}, ...
```

Returns the user with name "Superman".

```
const userSchema = new Schema(
    {
        name: String,
        age: Number
    }
)

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

User.findOne({xname: "Superman"}, ...
```

But when using `xname` in the filter document which does not exist in my schema neither in the collection as field the query returns the first document in my test collection (its not Superman).

Also look here similar issue: [Model.find Mongoose 6.012 always return all documents even though having filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69820475/model-find-mongoose-6-012-always-return-all-documents-even-though-having-filter)

Issue reported: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10763

Migration Guide to Mongoose 6:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#strictquery-is-removed-and-replaced-by-strict

Comment: Thank you that was the answer... ‍♂️ I needed to set the `index` to the `clubEmail` and  `findOne` of the `clubEmail`